# How long does a crate drop take in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

While playing Grand Theft Auto V online players are occasionally notified of a crate drop. A green circle appears on the map and a flare appears in the game world.

I have responded to a few of these crate drops notifications but am confused by how long it takes between the notification and the crate actually appearing.

Recently I spent over 15 minutes at the flare site shooting any player who came close (sorry guys, nothing personal) but the crate still didn't appear. I have come across two dropped crates, so I know they do drop at some point.

Is there a set time limit, a random time limit, or is the crate drop triggered by something else (like having a certain number of players occupying the drop zone)?

Comment: I often wonder the answer to this myself.

Comment: I saw a player use a fighter to shoot the crate plane down -_- I think waiting for crate doesn't worth. wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the normal crates spawn randomly when it comes to time, and if you go to the drop impound right after it shows on the map the crate will never spawn, I think it's a bug because one time I did that and I waited 3 real life hours, and one time when the inpound spawned I waited one ingame hour and the crate spawned.

I'm not sure about the special crates because I only saw an ingame notice about them only 2 times, but I think it's something like 1 day or 1 week in real life.

And when you see a special crate notice and it will say "special crate drop in *whatever* hours" it will mean ingame hours not real life hours.

hope this helped. :)

Comment: I read about the possible green circle so tried waiting around just outside the circle after being notified about the drop. Again I got bored of waiting and gave up.

You think that with people spending a 1-2 hours per online session they'd make sure the crates drop sooner rather than later. Sitting around declining job invites waiting for a crate that never appears isn't much fun.

Answer (score 0):

I seen something that said that it takes 4 game hours to show up. I have collected only 1 but tried for about 3 others.(was not success full) Now I am sitting here and it's been about 30 min real life time. I'm not sure what that is equal to online time, but im sure it's more then 4 hours online time. i have declined so many job's because i am hoping this is worth it.